# Sympy solve in python dosen't return anything

Tags: python, sympy

I have three equations and three unknowns I am trying to solve using sympy solve. I have the following code:

```
import math
from sympy import apart
from sympy.abc import x, y, z
from sympy import solve, symbols
x, y, z = symbols('x,y,z')

curr_location_x1=3
curr_location_y1=3
curr_location_z1=3

curr_location_x2=4
curr_location_y2=4
curr_location_z2=4

curr_location_x3=5
curr_location_y3=5
curr_location_z3=5

f_1=0.3
f_2=0.25
f_3=0.2

x_my=0.1
y_my=0.1
z_my=0.1

x_test=3.5
y_test=3.5
z_test=3.5
sol4=solve([math.log(f_3) + ((curr_location_x3-x_my)**2)/(2*(x**2)) + ((curr_location_y3-y_my)**2)/(2*(y**2)) + ((curr_location_z3-z_my)**2)/(2*(z**2)),math.log(f_2) + ((curr_location_x2-x_my)**2)/(2*(x**2)) + ((curr_location_y2-y_my)**2)/(2*(y**2)) + ((curr_location_z2-z_my)**2)/(2*(z**2)),math.log(f_1) + ((curr_location_x1-x_my)**2)/(2*(x**2)) + ((curr_location_y1-y_my)**2)/(2*(y**2)) + ((curr_location_z1-z_my)**2)/(2*(z**2)) ], [x, y, z])
print(sol4)
```

`

However, when I try to run this and print sol4 I get nothing, just '[]'. I don't understand why, since I double checked the function and it is correct.

Comment: You function is a multivariate inverse square function, it has no zeros

Comment: It has a negative constant, so it does actually have zeroes. The inverse square function might only be positive but the constant 'math.log(f_1)' is negative.

Comment: You are right, I missed that.